# Low Disk Space message, but disk usage says 377GB available

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, disk-usage

Ubuntu keeps popping up with a low disk space message

But when I click examine, it shows that I have 377GB available.

I'm running a dual boot Ubuntu 12.04/Windows 7 machine. When I set up the system, I made the mistake of not setting up separate partitions. I also made the mistake of not defragmenting the HDD before I installed Ubuntu. This probably has something to do with this error I'm getting, but I'm not really sure how to fix it at this point.

Results of df in terminal are below (sda3 is the Windows partition):

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/loop0      10698000   9191144    956764  91% /
udev             1912128         4   1912124   1% /dev
tmpfs             768628       868    767760   1% /run
none                5120         0      5120   0% /run/lock
none             1921564      5520   1916044   1% /run/shm
/dev/sda4      367694844 117809712 249885132  33% /host
/dev/sr0          419820    419820         0 100% /media/Suarez Disk 2
/dev/sda3      104857596  88757972  16099624  85% /media/62501F1F501EF98D
```

df -h:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/loop0       11G  8.8G  935M  91% /
udev            1.9G  4.0K  1.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           751M  868K  750M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            1.9G  5.5M  1.9G   1% /run/shm
/dev/sda4       351G  113G  239G  33% /host
/dev/sr0        410M  410M     0 100% /media/Suarez Disk 2
/dev/sda3       100G   85G   16G  85% /media/62501F1F501EF98D
```

Comment: Can you enter `df` into a terminal and paste the results here?

Comment: Perhaps it's your Ubuntu boot partition that's full of old Linux kernels. When do you get the error and what does it say?

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause is Wubi or the CD you have in your system or that you mounted your Windows partition in `/`.

> /dev/sr0        410M  410M     0 100%
>
> /dev/loop0       11G  8.8G  935M  91%

The "377GB" that you see available is because you mounted the hosts hard drive into `/`, if you move that partition to `/media` you will see the real numbers:

```
sudo mkdir /media/host
sudo mount --move /host /media/host
```

Comment: I did the commands you said, and it's still coming up with the low disk space error. I can't unmount /dev/loop0. What is it? I don't have any ISO files mounted that I'm aware of.

Comment: Are you using Wubi?